# a query displaying 0 instead of not showing

Tags: sql, gaps-and-islands

the following query is displaying the result i want except i want it to show 0 for each month with non production.

```
SELECT 
  DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(M, MONTH(PolicyDetails.IssuedDate), - 1)) AS Month, 
  SUM(PolicyDetails.Premium) AS TotalProduction, 
  DATENAME(YEAR, PolicyDetails.IssuedDate) AS Year 
FROM PolicyDetails INNER JOIN Clients 
ON PolicyDetails.ClientId = Clients.ClientId 
WHERE (Clients.Username = @Username) 
GROUP BY MONTH(PolicyDetails.IssuedDate), DATENAME(YEAR, PolicyDetails.IssuedDate)


Month   Total Production -$$
  2019 - August 30.00
  2019 - October    45.00
```

in this table i want to show "2019 - September" with Total Production = 0 instead of displaying nothing. How ??

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using (which looks like SQL Server).  (2) Your month arithmetic is strange.  Why do you want the previous month for the  month, but not the year?

Comment: When `PolicyDetails.IssuedDate` is in January you'll get December as Month and the correct value for Year, you need to calculate the previous month also for Year

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show all months in the data, probably the simplest method is to use conditional aggregation.  Your calculation of the month seems awkward.  You seem to want the previous month, so:

```
SELECT DATENAME(YEAR, pd.IssuedDate) AS Year,
       DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, pd.IssuedDate)) AS Month, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN c.Username = @Username THEN pd.Premium ELSE 0 END) AS TotalProduction          
FROM PolicyDetails pd INNER JOIN
     Clients c
     ON pd.ClientId = c.ClientId 
GROUP BY DATENAME(YEAR, pd.IssuedDate), DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, pd.IssuedDate))
ORDER BY MIN(pd.IssuedDate)
```

This assumes that you have at least one row per month in the data.

Otherwise, the canonical approach is to generate the months you want (using a derived table or recursive CTE or calendar table).  Your month arithmetic is a bit awkward for that solution.  It would look like:

```
SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, months.mstart)),
       MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, months.mstart)),
       COALESCE(SUM(pd.Premium), 0) AS TotalProduction          
FROM (VALUES (CONVERT(DATE, '2019-08-01')),
             (CONVERT(DATE, '2019-09-01')),
             (CONVERT(DATE, '2019-10-01'))
     ) months(mstart) LEFT JOIN
     PolicyDetails pd
     ON pd.IssuedDate >= DATEADD(month, -1, months.mstart)  AND
        pd.IssuedDate < months.mstart LEFT JOIN
     Clients c
     ON pd.ClientId = c.ClientId AND
        c.Username = @Username
GROUP BY YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, months.mstart)),
         MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, months.mstart))
ORDER BY MIN(pd.IssuedDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that might be a usecase for SQL-IF.

Syntax as follows:

```
SELECT IF([condition], "YES", "NO");
```

In your case, try to combine that with your query.

Maybe like this:

```
SELECT IF([subquery > 0] AS X, X, 0);
```

If-Condition Like:

```
SELECT IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PolicyDetails ) > 0, 1, 0);
```

But you will have to combine that output with your existing query posted above, to gain the output if the table is filled.

Comment: There is no `IF` in "SQL" (as in "standard SQL")  - some dialects like T-SQL (Microsoft) support it though

Comment: I usually work with mySQL - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_if.asp
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-if-statement-introduction-and-overview/